# iOS - PLIST - Access other plist values from within plist

Tags: ios, plist

I have a PLIST file in my app that contains various configuration data.  Some of the data are URLs for accessing a server.  This server hosts JSON files for several different versions of our code.  What I want to be able to do is have a value in the PLIST file that has the version and then be able to reference it from other values.  So the url value in the plist could be https://www.company.com/${VERSION}/jsonfile.svc (where ${VERSION} is a different key int he same plist file).

Answer (score 3):

As bshirley mentioned there is nothing automatic but Objective-C can help you with that. Below is a simple implementation of a `NSDictionary` category called `VariableExpansion` that demonstrates how this could be implemented (note that this is not fully tested but serves primarily to demonstrate the way you could make this automatic. Also, `expandedObjectForKey` assumes you are dealing with `NSString`s so you might need to tweak it a bit.

```
// In file NSDictionary+VariableExpansion.h
@interface NSDictionary (VariableExpansion)

- (NSString*)expandedObjectForKey:(id)aKey;

@end

// In file NSDictionary+VariableExpansion.m
#import "NSDictionary+VariableExpansion.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (VariableExpansion)

- (NSString*)expandedObjectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    NSString* value = [self objectForKey:aKey];

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\$\\{([^\\{\\}]*)\\}"
                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                  error:&error];

    __block NSMutableString *mutableValue = [value mutableCopy];
    __block int offset = 0;

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:value options:0
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [value length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
    {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    matchRange.location += offset;

    NSString* varName = [regex replacementStringForResult:match
                           inString:mutableValue
                             offset:offset
                           template:@"$1"];

    NSString *varValue = [self objectForKey:varName];
    if (varValue)
    {
        [mutableValue replaceCharactersInRange:matchRange
                    withString:varValue];
        // update the offset based on the replacement
        offset += ([varValue length] - matchRange.length);
    }
    }];

    return mutableValue;
}

@end


// To test the code, first import this category:
#import "NSDictionary+VariableExpansion.h"

// Sample NSDictionary.
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"http://${HOST}/${VERSION}/bla", @"URL",
        @"1.0", @"VERSION",
        @"example.com", @"HOST", nil];

// And the new method that expands any variables (if it finds them in the PLIST as well).
NSLog(@"%@", [dict expandedObjectForKey:@"URL"]);
```

The result of the last step is `http://example.com/1.0/bla` showing that you could use multiple variables in a single value. If a variable is not found it will not be touched in your original string.

Since you are using PLIST as your source, use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` as in

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried anything? this is fairly straightforward, convert it as you are mentioning, the method of particular use: `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`.

Comment: Right now I am pulling the values out and constructing the strings from within code.  I want this automatically done withint he plist so when I pull the values, the version number is inserted according to the value in the plist file.

Comment: there is nothing "automatic" for you to leverage, load the dictionary from a file, make it mutable, iterate over the values and substitute the values you're interested in.  if it's something you'd like to use in the future, make it a category on `NSMutableDictionary` so that you might make use of it elsewhere